# ngOnInit vs ionViewDidLoad in ionic 2 or ionic 2+

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

Which one will I use for initializing data and why?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.type = 'category';
    this.getData();
    this.setData();
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.type = 'category';
    this.getData();
    this.setData();
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`ngOnInit` is a life cycle hook called by Angular2 to indicate that Angular is done creating the component.

`ionViewDidLoad` is related to the Ionic's `NavController` lifeCycle events. It runs when the page has loaded. This event only happens once per page being created.

Basically both are good places for initializing the component's data.

But for using `ngOnInit` you need to implement the Angular's `OnInit` class,
In the other hand `ionViewDidLoad` could be only defined for components that are  pushed/popped from a `NavController`.

So I would say use the `ionViewDidLoad` for components in the `NavController` stack and `ngOnInit` for other components.

Comment: nice  explanation.Thank you.

Comment: What lifeCycle events fires every time the page is refreshed?

Comment: Excellent answer.
I would like to add there is also *ionViewWillEnter*. The primary difference between the two ion-page events is that ...WillEnter() always fires before the component renders whereas ...DidLoad() will **not** fire for pages that are cached.

https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/

Answer (score 4):

ionViewDidLoad firing is close related to the NavController.

If you need a hook for a component that is rendered independent of the NavController (not all components in an ionic 2 app are pages) you should use [angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) instead of [ionic navcontroller hooks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

Now, which one is suitable for you, it depends on the implementation case.

Anyway the names of all those hooks are self-explanatory most of the times.

Answer (score 2):

Both function works the same way, they get called when the view is initially loaded into the DOM.

Great blog about ionic2s lifecycle hooks [here](https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/).