# using ngOnInit() method on Ionic page - whether we need to import OnInit and write Class implements OnInit?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngoninit

This the code that is used to load a variable with data on the page, using `ngOnInit` method:

[image: ngOnInit]

However, I notice that even if we don't import the OnInit (line 1) and don't write `implements OnInit` (line 10), the method is still invoked. What is the best practice?

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: @veben the method works even if we don't import and implement. It is sufficient that we write ngOnInit(){...do something...} and this works. Hence the question.

Comment: @veben thats.. not true. You can use without it

Comment: here https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#interfaces-are-optional-technically

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you are using Ionic, I would suggest checking ionic lifecycle events. More information can be found [here](https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/).

To answer your question, if you want to use OnInit, you should import the OnInit and add `implements OnInit` to the class declaration (as you have already done).  If you fail to do so, the Typescript type checks would give you an error message (since this is typescript). It's a good practice thing, and validators won't shout about invalid code.

If you don't want to add `implements OnInit`, you could use event `ionViewDidLoad` or any other that would fit best for your need.

So to summarize regarding the best practice:

- Use one of the Ionic events, if you are developing Ionic app and creating a page.
- Use ngOnInit and do `implements OnInit` next to class declaration if you are developing an Angular app OR if you need to do something on initialization of a component within Ionic.

Comment: You can use ngOninit without implementing the interface(it is good practice to implement them). And you can use angular lifecycle hooks in ionic as well. for eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703271/ngoninit-vs-ionviewdidload-in-ionic-2/43703490

Comment: @SurajRao Sure you can! That is what I wrote, that you can use ngOnInit, but it is not the best practice to use it without implements OnInit statement. Regarding the ionViewDidLoad, since author is asking it for a component that is loading a page, then I provided a suggestion to use ionViewDidLoad instead of ngOnInit.

Comment: Your answer seems to suggest not to use angular hooks in Ionic which isnt necessarily true. Otherwise I dont see anything wrong