# Can someone explain to me why I don't see connection status in this code?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need help with ionic Network plugin. Here's a code, but it doesn't work for me. No console log or any other modals. No errors.
at the top

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getWarrentsNumber();
    let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
    });

    disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();

    let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        console.log('network connected!');
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
                console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
            }
        }, 3000);
    });

    connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Remove both `unsubscribe()` and try again please. We will fix this if this solve the problem.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi i've just commented both two lines  // disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe(); and // connectSubscription.unsubscribe();  but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. For now, leave them commented. Who call the function `ionViewDidLoad()` ?

Comment: ionViewDidload() is the function from  ionic app. It means it will open any functions in them while app is opened. I also tried to create a function left from ionviewdidload but still happens without any progress.

Comment: It could maybe be a dumb question, but are you sure that this function is called? Have you tried putting a breakpoint at `this.getWarrentsNumber();` to see if the code is reached?

Comment: Are you sure you get a connection? You have to connect to network after your app opens. If you are already connected to WiFi I don't believe onConnect will emit anything

Comment: But that is the point i mean @Arif . Im testing an app from chrome browser, and app need automatically to scan is there connection or not.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi i've commented that line, and everything is the same. When user log in to an app, on HomePage, i need to scan is there connection or not.

Comment: I'll investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the quote from plugin's official [github repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)

> The online event fires when a previously unconnected device receives a
>   network connection to allow an application access to the Internet. It
>   relies on the same information as the Connection API, and fires when
>   the connection.type changes from NONE to any other value.

As you can see onConnect will only emit something when previously unconnected device receives a network connection.

To check on startup if device is online you can directly check `this.network.type`

**Or**

You can create a service which will handle all these

```
@Injectable()
export class MyNetworkService implements OnInit {
  public connection: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor(private network: Network, private platform: Platform) {

    this.connection = this.network.type;
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        this.connection = 'something';
      });
      this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        this.connection = 'none';
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._setCurrentConnectionType();

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.network.onConnect().pipe(timer(3000)).subscribe(this._onConnectHandler);
      this.network.onDisconnect().pipe(timer(3000)).subscribe(this._onDisconnectHandler);
    });
  }

  private _onConnectHandler= () => this.connection.next(this.network.type);

  private _onDisconnectHandler = () => this.connection.next('offline');
}
```

And then you can inject your service where-ever you want and subscribe to connection.

```
constructor(private myNetworkService: MyNetworkService) {
  this.myNetworkService.connection.subscribe(type => {
    // you might filter out nulls
    // Before subscribe add .pipe(filter(type => type !== null))
  })

}
```

Comment: I need to check for connection not only on startup, i need it in few pages....also when user get a connection he will see a toast msg that connection is OK or NOT.  THats the point.

Comment: With behaviour subject you can even do myNetworkService.connection.getValue() or subscribe where-ever you want. It doesn't matter if it is a startup or some nested component

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables `connectSubscription` & `disconnectSubscription` as class properties and then try to `unsubscribe()` them in `ioniViewWillLeave()` hook instead of `ionViewDidLoad()`.
So the code would look similar to the following -

```
connectSubscription: any;
disconnectSubscription: any;

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getWarrentsNumber();
    this.disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
    });

    this.connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        console.log('network connected!');
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
                console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
            }
        }, 3000);
    });
}

ioniViewWillLeave() {
    this.disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code works properly but it works dependent platform like android or ios. It may not console anything on the browser I think. Please test your application with respect to the platform device.

or else you can use ngOnInit() instead of ionViewDidLoad();

Comment: cant user ngOnInit() instead of ionVIewDidLoad(); because its not an angular app..Its ionic app.

Comment: you can use ngOnInit() but the thing is you have to implement the class with OnInit.
can you look into this
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703271/ngoninit-vs-ionviewdidload-in-ionic-2
I check your code with ngOnInit() on my application it is working.

Comment: Please import the OnInit before you using and Implement the class with OnInit
//
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class YourClassName implements OnInit {
}